# Which js library to use for creating not complicated animation with html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-animation

I want to write some animation with html5 canvas element. I found that there are some js libraries that help to leverage canvas functionality. For example KineticJS, FabricJS. But I don't know which library to use.
What is pros and cons when using this libraries? Or may be you know even better implementation?

**edit**
I'm going to create something similar to static picture, but with piece оf animation. For example floating clouds on the sky, flower where you can tear off a petal and throw it. May be some animation with sun. This is general description, hope this helps.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do, could you elaborate to give us more of an idea of what you want...? i.e. just a Rectangle moving? ... ?

Comment: You aren't talking about just animation there, you are talking about interactivity through canvas.

Answer (score 0):

There is Processing.js, which is a port of Processing for Java. Processing.js is ideal for 2d images.

Raphaël uses svg to draw images, which results in more compatibility.

For 3d there is Three.js, which uses both canvas and webgl.

There are a lot of different libraries around, you should first find out what you want to draw.

http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

[cgSceneGraph](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/) is a javascript animation framework providing a full animation engine with timelines, animation keys, ...
It also provides helper methods to easily add animations on every attribute of an element.

The example on the home page of the website is exactly what you talk about, so it should fit your need :)

Answer (score -2):

For simple animations forget the canvas and use `position: absolute` div elements with background image that you can move around with CSS transform translate3d and scale3d.